# map between projective schemes induced by rational points

Tags: algebraic-geometry, schemes, projective-space, projective-schemes

Given a map between $\mathbb P^n_{\mathbb C}$ and itself, given by
$$ [x_0:\dots:x_n] \mapsto [p_0(x):\dots:p_n(x)]$$
where $p_i$ are homogeneous polynomials of the same degree, how do I find the corresponding map between the Projective schemes?

I think I have to find a map between the polinomial rings, such that the counterimage of the maximal ideal
$$ (\{a_ix_j-a_jx_i\}_{i,j})$$
is the maximal ideal
$$ (\{p_i(a)y_j-p_j(a)y_i\}_{i,j}) $$
for every $a\in \mathbb{C}^{n+1}$, but I don't see an easy way to do so.

For example, I tried with the map between $\mathbb P^1$ 
$$ [x_0,x_1]\mapsto [x_0(x_0-x_1)^2:x_1^3] $$ 
but I got nothing. Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The map

\begin{align}
\mathbb{P}^n_\mathbb{C} &\to \mathbb{P}^m_\mathbb{C} \\
[x_0 : \cdots : x_n] & \mapsto [p_0(\overline{x}):\cdots:p_m(\overline{x})]
\end{align}

corresponds to the ring homomorphism

\begin{align}
\mathbb{C}[y_0, \ldots, y_m] &\to \mathbb{C}[x_0, \ldots, x_n] \\
y_i &\mapsto p_i(x_0, \ldots, x_m)
\end{align}

Comment: I'll agree only when you prove me that for all $i,j$ and $a\in\mathbb C^{n+1}$
$$ p_i(a)p_j(x) - p_i(x)p_j(a) \in (\{x_ka_h-x_ha_k \}_{h,k}) $$

Comment: Nevermind, I proved it myself